# Linq result to ViewData and show result in PartialView

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core

Can anyone help me I beginner in programming Asp.Net.Core MVC
I have this two methods in HomeController.cs and trying to make a query from database FactoryContext table MoldingOrders and make a view specific column to PartialView. I was trying to find some solution on web but nothing help enough.

```
public ActionResult Index() 
{ return View(); }
        
public PartialViewResult Backlog()
        {
            try { 
                var contract =  (from auftrag in FactoryContext.MoldingOrders
                                 select auftrag);
                contract.ToListAsync();
                ViewData["ContractList"] = contract;
                return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/_Backlog.cshtml");
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return null;
            }
        }
```

This is the model MoldingOrders.cs it was scaffold from existing database

```
public partial class MoldingOrders
    {
        public MoldingOrders()
        {
            MoldingOrdersPlan = new HashSet<MoldingOrdersPlan>();
        }
        
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ExportDate { get; set; }
        public string Auftrag { get; set; }
        public string Material { get; set; }
        public string Materialkurztext { get; set; }
        public string Fertsteu { get; set; }
        public string Disponent { get; set; }
        public string Eckende { get; set; }
        public int? Sollmenge { get; set; }
        public string Materialfixed { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<MoldingOrdersPlan> MoldingOrdersPlan { get; set; }
```

Partial View - _Backlog.cshtml

```
@using ProductionPlanningApp.Models;
@model IEnumerable<MoldingOrders>

@{
     List<MoldingOrders> ContractList = (List<MoldingOrders>)ViewData["EmployeesList"];
}

<html>
 <body>
    <div class="overflow-auto position-absolute position-table">
        <table class="table table-bordered w-auto">
            <thead class="table-dark">
                <tr>
                <th class="text-md-center">BACKLOG</th>
               </tr>
            </thead>
           <tbody>
                @foreach(var item in ViewData["contracts"] as IEnumerable<ProductionPlanningApp.Models.MoldingOrders>)
                {
                    <tr class="d-flex">
                        <td>
                            <button type="button"class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-link btn-sm">@item.Auftrag</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
           </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Code will run but after loading will trow System.NullReferenceException
[image]

Comment: `contract.ToListAsync()` returns `Task`. You have to do `var contactList = await contract.ToListAsync()` and assign `contactList` to `ViewData`. Also names of values retrieved from ViewData are different.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm mistaken, but in your first codeblock you use "ContractList" as a key for ViewData, but in the last codeblock you try to access "contracts".

Sorry if I'm mistaken, this was something which made me wonder.

EDIT:
If both should contain the same data, the keys should match. Try changing the key "contracts" to "ContractList".

Comment: Is this an answer?

Comment: It was rather meant as a guess where the issue could have its origin. I will make it more obvious in the answer/post. Sorry for the unclearance in my post.

Answer (score 0):

You should change contracts to ContractList.

```
@foreach(var item in ViewData["ContractList"] as IEnumerable<ProductionPlanningApp.Models.MoldingOrders>)
```

Comment: I changed to ViewData["ContractList"] it was mistake but still there is the same error with System.NullReferenceException

Comment: You may hava a problem with the index.cshtml call,you can add a breakpoint at ViewData["ContractList"] to check whether it has data.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `ViewData["contracts"]` in your action:

```
public PartialViewResult Backlog()
        {
            try { 
                var contract =  (from auftrag in FactoryContext.MoldingOrders
                                 select auftrag);
                contract.ToListAsync();
                ViewData["contracts"] = contract;
                return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/_Backlog.cshtml");
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I am setting it `ViewData["contracts"]` on 7 row.